# If i factory reset my android device and i have my app installed as system app, will it revoke all permission of app

Tags: android

I have my app installed in my android device as system app in /system/app directory. Later location permission, read write external storage permissions are given by the user at runtime. If the user decides to factory reset the device, will all the permission given in runtime to the system app revoked?

I have not tried this in my android device yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will remove all the permissions.